# Asking a negative question

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I've heard that it is supposed to be "less demanding" (or something in that regard) to ask a negative question when you're asking for a favor or anything alike.

Let's say I want to turn this sentence into a negative one:

> スカイプで話しましょうか？

**How do I go about doing it?** I want to convey the following meaning: "Should we talk over skype?"

Comment: The same happens in English. The basic, straight-foward question would be `Do we talk on Skype?` But in common usage, people make that less direct by negating it, or making it voluntary &c.: `Can we talk...`, `Would you like to talk...`, `How about talking on...`, `Couldn't we talk...`, `Do you wanna talk...`, and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By chance I just read something new (for me) on these expressions which explains Choko's answer (〜ませんか？):

> 〜ましょうか？ is used when the speaker is in a position to make the relevant decision. When used as an invitation toward someone with who the speaker is not too close it can sound too familiar.

==>>

> 〜ませんか？ is used as a polite invitation. The meaning is similar to "Would you like to ~?" in English. (Don't confuse with 〜ないんですか？ which means "You're not...")

*Reference: "Japanese Grammar in Use" - E Manita & J Blagdon p188*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for making a clear distinction between these 2 ways of asking.

Answer (score 5):

I think I would probably say スカイプで話しませんか？

Comment: Is it true that 「～ませんか。」 is less demanding than 「～ましょうか。」?

Comment: @3to5businessdays It is the difference between "shall we~/let's~" and "Aren't we going to"/"Will you not..": To go one step further the positive, as in ~てくれますか, is less pushy than the negative ~てくれませんか.

Comment: @3to5businessdays: see my answer (below)