# いきませんか vs いきますか

Tags: grammar

I have pretty much just started learning japanese and so far I can only recall encountering  いきますか as in "shall we go".

But while doing an exercise on marugoto I saw this sentence that confused me.

> A: あした　にほんの　えいがが　ありますよ。
>
> B: いっしょに　見に　いきませんか

So the question here is why is it いきませんか and not いきますか
and why is it wrong to answer

> B: いっしょに　いきましょう

isn't that also grammatically correct as in lets go together?

Comment: Does Tim's explanation here answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/asking-a-negative-question/18651#18651 Or jarmonso7's explanation here? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/71923/what-is-the-difference-between-何を-ましょうか-何を-ますか-and-何を-ませんか/71952#71952